# Access/SQL Cumulative Query wth GroupBy

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need a query that basically improves upon a query I already have. My original post was here: [Access Cumulative Total by Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57042245/access-cumulative-total-by-date)

The existing query is a running sum of the energy capacity online as of the end of the year. I need one that makes the same one but broken out by project type, preferably in a crosstab format.

The project capacity and online date is stored in the Projects table and the Alternative Energy Type that I need the table to be grouped by is in a different table, Project Types, and the two are related through a type ID.

I'm not very good with SQL, so I've been trying to just add in the Project Types table  from the Access Query Builder, but just adding in another groupby column with the Alternative Energy Type

Original:

```
SELECT Year(p.[Online Date]) AS yr, (SELECT SUM(p2.[System Size AC])
        FROM Projects as p2
        WHERE YEAR(p2.[Online Date]) <= YEAR(p.[Online Date])
       ) AS running_sum
FROM Projects AS p
GROUP BY Year([Online Date]);
```

Modified (wrong):

```
SELECT Year(p.[Online Date]) AS yr, (SELECT SUM(p2.[System Size AC])
        FROM Projects as p2
        WHERE YEAR(p2.[Online Date]) <= YEAR(p.[Online Date])
       ) AS running_sum, [Project Types].[Alternative Energy Type]
FROM [Project Types] INNER JOIN Projects AS p ON [Project Types].[Type ID] = p.[Project Type]
GROUP BY Year([Online Date]), [Project Types].[Alternative Energy Type];
```

The results of the modified query just show the total yearly running sum with the Alterntaive Energy Types next to them. This isn't correct because it's just showing the same total over and over, nothing is broken out.

I need it to be broken out so that it answers the question "How much rooftop solar did we have as of 12/31/2015, 12/31/2016, etc and how much offsite wind did we have as of 12/31/2015, 12/31/2016, etc"

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an equality to the correlated subquery by grouping field, *Alternative Energy Type*:

```
SELECT t.[Alternative Energy Type],
       YEAR(p.[Online Date]) AS yr,            
       (SELECT SUM(subp.[System Size AC])
        FROM Projects subp
        INNER JOIN [Project Types] subt 
                ON subt.[Type ID] = subp.[Project Type]
        WHERE YEAR(subp.[Online Date]) <= YEAR(p.[Online Date])
          AND subt.[Alternative Energy Type] = t.[Alternative Energy Type]
       ) AS running_sum
FROM Projects p
INNER JOIN [Project Types] t
        ON t.[Type ID] = p.[Project Type]
GROUP BY t.[Alternative Energy Type],
         YEAR(p.[Online Date]);
```

For crosstab, first run a [make-table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-make-table-query-96424f9e-82fd-411e-aca4-e21ad0a94f1b) action query since the running sum calculation will cause issues

```
SELECT * 
INTO RunningSumTbl
FROM RunningSumQ
```

Then run the [crosstab](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8):

```
TRANSFORM Sum(q.running_sum) AS SumOfRunningSum
SELECT r.[Alternative Energy Type]
FROM RunningSumTbl r
GROUP BY r.[Alternative Energy Type]
PIVOT r.[yr];
```

Use `PIVOT` clause to subset and order columns:

```
PIVOT r.[yr] IN (2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015)
```